# Tkinter- index is not working using insert method

Tags: python, tkinter, indexing, insert

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300") 
root.minsize(height=560) 
root.title("text editor")
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)          
# packing scrollbar 
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)                     
text_info = Text(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) 
text_info.pack(fill=BOTH)
text_info.insert(2.5,"html page")                   
# configuring the scrollbar 
scrollbar.config(command=text_info.yview)
root.mainloop()
```

Here I've mentioned 2.5 means second line and fifth column but it's printing at 1.0 at the beginning
so how do I print my text at the second line?

Answer (score 0):

Insert doesn't work that way. It only inserts at a location, given there is text behind it. So if you really want to insert a text at say `n=2` and `m=5`:

```
n,m = 2,5
pad = "\n"*(n-1)+" "*(m-1)
text_info.insert(1.0,pad+"html page")
```

OR

```
n,m = 2,5
pad = "\n"*(n-1)+" "*(m-1)
text_info.insert(1.0,pad)
text_info.insert(2.5,"html page")
```

You can learn more about this [here](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/)